# Unity application for Windows Phone crashes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-phone

I have written very simple application in Unity for Windows Phone.

Aquarium background, bubbles (particle system) and fishes moving from left to right and right to left.

I published app to Windows Phone Store for free and in reports there are many crashes.

Stack trace which can I export:

```
App: AquariumInPhone
OS version: 8.0
Problem function: Unknown
Exception type: c0000005
30-day crash count: 23
Stack trace:

Frame    Image          Function                             Offset        
0        ntdll          RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection            0x0000007e    
1        ntdll          RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended    0x00000060    
2        unityplayer                                         0x002ef5ac
```

This is very simple application, but crashes :(

Fishes moving left have code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Fish1 : MonoBehaviour {

    float speed = 0.0032f;
    Vector3 startPoint;
    Vector3 currentPosition;
    System.Random r = new System.Random ();

    void Start()
    {    
        startPoint = transform.position;
        currentPosition = transform.position;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position).x < -0.2f)
        {
            int newY = r.Next(0, 5);

            if(r.Next(0, 2) == 0)
                newY = -newY;

            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(12.0f, (float)newY, 0.0f);
            currentPosition = pos;
            transform.position = currentPosition;
        }
        else
        {
            currentPosition.x--;
            transform.position += (currentPosition + startPoint) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Fishes moving right have code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Fish2 : MonoBehaviour {

float speed = 0.005f;
Vector3 startPoint;
Vector3 currentPosition;
System.Random r = new System.Random ();

void Start()
{    
    startPoint = transform.position;
    currentPosition = transform.position;
}

void Update ()
{
    if (Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position).x > 1.2f)
    {
        int newY = r.Next(0, 5);

        if(r.Next(0, 2) == 0)
            newY = -newY;

        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(-12.0f, (float)newY, 0.0f);
        currentPosition = pos;
        transform.position = currentPosition;
    }
    else
    {
        currentPosition.x++;
        transform.position += (currentPosition + startPoint) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
}
```

What can be the reason of crash? How can I fix this?

Greets, David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the problem seems to be related to the Unity Engine itself, it would be better to post your problem on the [Unity Support Forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/forums/50-Windows-Development). The devs are watching the forums and are more likely able to help you.

It could be some problematic setting or even a bug in the engine. For example, I had an app for the Windows Store where only one of the scenes would crash. In my case the crash only occurred when I used the development build setting and it was crashing before executing my code, so in the end it wasn't a problem with my code.